# iOS: Disable automatic space insertion when pasting

Tags: ios, copy-paste

When pasting text into a text editing window on iOS (anywhere – browser text field like the one I’m typing in now, address bar, iOS search bar, etc.), iOS seems to try to make an educated guess as to whether or not it should insert a space before the pasted text. Well, I say ‘educated’ … the actual logic seems to be to add a space if there isn’t one already, regardless of what comes before.

To me, this is extremely frustrating, because I *never, under any circumstances* want it to insert a space before my pasted text. If I want a space, I will type a space.

I frequently find myself pasting individual hard-to-type characters (for example when typing [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)), and this is practically impossible to do elegantly because everything you paste becomes a separate word, and then you need to try to use the terrible fine-selection cursor thingy to move one character back and delete a space.<sup>1</sup>

Needless to say, doing the same thing on macOS works exactly as expected.

Is there **some way** to disable this behaviour and always paste exactly what is in the clipboard, with no extra spaces being added anywhere?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Even worse, if the copied text is a combining Unicode character, such as a diacritic, it seems to be **completely impossible** to achieve the desired result, as far as I can tell. For example, yesterday I wanted to write the title *Scáṫán na ḃFíréan: Leaḃar urnuiḋṫe caitliciḋe* in a Tweet on my phone, so I found a website where I could copy the combining dot above diacritic; but typing ‘Scát’ and then pasting the combining diacritic left me with ‘Scát˙’, with a space added before the diacritic, rather than the expected ‘Scáṫ’.</sup>

Comment: On my iOS phone I have never experienced spaces added before pasted text and this text was no exception: Scáṫán na ḃFíréan: Leaḃar urnuiḋṫe caitliciḋe

Comment: I've never experienced this problem is 10 years of iOS use. Are you using a 3rd-party keyboard?

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Well, that’s odd. I just tested on this very page, and it reacts as described in the question. What exactly did you copy, though? To reproduce, what I did was click “Add a comment”, copy just one letter from your comment (“ṫ”), type “Scá” (no spaces) into the comment box, tap at the end of that and hit _Paste_. The result: “Scá ṫ” with a space.

Comment: @fsb No, just the standard built-in English keyboard. I do _have_ a third-party keyboard installed (IPA), but I’m not generally using it when pasting, and I don’t see how it could have anything to do with it anyway, since copy-paste doesn’t really interact with the keyboard.